# Strongly continuous measure [reduced]

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebra, lebesgue-measure

**Let us first give our definitions: the word CHARGE means finitely additive measure**
[image]

> strongly continuous finitely additive measure is nonatomic, but not conversely. Here is the example:
>   [image]
>
> how cannot we partitioned $X$ into finite sets $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}$ in $\mathscr{F}$, each of measure $<\varepsilon=1/2$. If we assume $\varepsilon=1/2^i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$, there is no partition. But I cannot see why for $\varepsilon=1/2$ there is no partition for $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no proper subset of $[0,1/4)\cup[3/4,1]$ in your algebra, so some partition cell containing it must be a superset, which has therfore measure at least $1/2$.

Comment: could you please be more explicit, which partition will be failed

Comment: Any partition of $[0,1]$ into sets in your algebra.

Comment: Oh I see, the sets in the partition need not be elements in the algebra. I think this what made me confused.

Comment: @ZirkoTammado No, the partition sets need to be in your algebra. And there is no proper subset of $[0,1/4)\cup[3/4,1]$ in the algebra. So in a partition by sets in the algebra, there must be a single cell that contains all of $[0,1/4)\cup[3/4,1]$ and has therefore measure at least $1/2$ (it actually has to be even larger). Since this holds for all partitions into sets in the algebra, the claim is proven.

Comment: Dear Michael I thank you so much for the answer, I understand what you have written. In order for a measure on an algebra to be strongly continuous. The algebra should cover (approximately) the whole space $X$. I hope I am correct.

Comment: @ZirkoTammado It should cover it with "small pieces".